# Image in UserControl makes UserControl invisible, but makes Window background visible

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I took [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32257/A-Style-for-Round-Glassy-WPF-Buttons) example of making round glass buttons and make a User Control from it with minimum influence. Third button is my from User Control, all others - original from the example: (sorry, reputation not enough to put images in comfortable way)

[image: https://i.imgur.com/aBE8AjQ.png]

But just after I add image to Control I see

[image: https://i.imgur.com/FYPItVf.png]

Image is added the same way as to second button

```
            <Button Style="{StaticResource GlassButton}" Width="50" Height="50" Background="#FF1D5BBA"  Margin="10">
                <Image Width="40" Height="35" Source="images\vista_flag.png"/>
            </Button>

            <GlassButtonControl:GlassButton Width="70" Height="70" Margin="0">
                <Image Width="40" Height="35" Source="images\vista_flag.png"/>
            </GlassButtonControl:GlassButton>
```

[Full solution](https://yadi.sk/d/0G2PpKrNv76uiQ)

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT1 -> EDIT3**

**EDIT2:**

as Peter Duniho sujested, minimal code for reproduce case

UserControl project's XAML. Button with colored background:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GreenButtonControl.GreenButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GreenButtonControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid>
        <Button Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"  Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl project's C#:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace GreenButtonControl
{
    public partial class GreenButton : UserControl
    {
        public GreenButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Window XAML (image itself should be changed to any existsing with transparency):

```
<GreenButtonControl:GreenButton Width="50" Height="50">
    <Image Width="40" Height="40" Source="images\vista_flag.png"/>
</GreenButtonControl:GreenButton>
```

The problem is that UserControl disapear and Window backround is shown under the transparent image.

**EDIT3:**

Solutions I found for now to avoid such a behaviour:

1. Place Image in UserControl code and make parameter to set it from Window code.
2. Place image not inside a control, but over it:

```
            <Grid Width="70" Height="70">
                <GlassButtonControl:GlassButton/>
                <Image Width="40" Height="40" Source="images\vista_flag.png"/>
            </Grid>
```

But that's bring new problems to catch triggers "MouseOver" and others...

3. Place UserControl in container and make Image transparent to Mouse events

```
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50">
                <GreenButtonControl:GreenButton Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
                <Image Width="40" Height="40" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="images\vista_flag.png"/>
            </Grid>
```

That's perfect decision for required behaviour for now

But the question still is. Why any internal Element makes UserControl invisible?

Comment: I can't see your full solution, but what is the problem using the style as is, since it is working and your usercontrol isn't.

Comment: Actualy I do so for now. But it will be usefull to make library for future use in adjacent projects. We have limitations to use third party code even open source.But the problem scaring me with it's simplicity.

Comment: Your question should be entirely self-contained, and include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. You can offer _in addition_ a link to a full project, but you should not expect most people to bother to look at the link, and your question _must_ not rely on that link for comprehension of the question.

Comment: Totally agree with you, and tried to do exactly as you said. Minimal example in this case assumes at least two projects: one us UserControl and second is Window. I think that full listing will take inapropriate space. Even without glass button example that I placed in UserControl. The proplem persist even if you make green button in UserControl and some image inside it in Window. But that's anyway must be two projects in a solution. So I think it simplier to take applied solution instead of making own.